# SQL count from 2 tables with true/false

Tags: sql, count

I have 2 tables:

- Table1: Key,Brand,Type,European,RefNr
- Table2: Key,Owner,Address,RefNr

The RefNr in both tables is the unique identifier and European in Table1 is a True/False field.

My question is how do I do a count of all owners with an European car?

Answer (score 1):

With the information given, I'd say you are looking for a join with a simple where condition?

```
select count(distinct t2.owner)
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.refnr = t2.refnr
where t1.european = true;
```

The `distinct t2.owner` is necessary in case someone owns more than one car.

Comment: . . I think you are right given how the query is phrased ("count of all owners").

Answer (score 1):

A solution for Sql Server follows:

```
Select count(t2.Owner) as EuropeanCarOwner
From Table1 t1
Inner join Table2 t2 on t2.RefNr = t1.RefNr
where t1.European = 1
```

Please note that is European column is not type of boolean but varchar, you can do t1.European = 'true' in the while clause

If a person can own multiple cars and each car is entered as a different record, each owner can be counted only one time if required via: `count(distinct t2.owner)`

Answer (score 0):

Not that it states which DBMS you are using, this should work in SSMS;

```
    SELECT  COUNT(*) AS EuroOwners
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.RefNr = t2.RefNr AND t1.European = 1
```

Comment: DBMS = Access with classic ASP. Your solution works great, the only thing I had to change is: `INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.RefNr = t2.RefNr WHERE t1.European = TRUE `